# MFC form in separate thread

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

I have console MFC form application that consists from one form. In MFC application contructor  thread with task is started :

```
CfbSrvApp::CfbSrvApp()
{
AfxBeginThread(MTServerThread,0);
}
```

`MTServerThread` procedure sometimes needs to show simple text input or yes/no form.

How to create MFC form in separate `MTServerThread`.

Main form sometimes can be minimised to tray, but input forms should appear to desktop anyway.

Answer (score 0):

1. Derive a class from CWinThread.
2. Overwrite InitInstance
3. Create the Dialog there as known with DoModal
4. Create the new Thread with AfxBeginThread and RUNTIME_CLASS(CYourNewCWiNThreadClass)

Answer (score 0):

> Main form sometimes can be minimised to tray, but input forms should
>   appear to desktop anyway.

For what you want to achieve, it is better to create Modeless dialog in the main thread itself. Let the background server thread update the UI of the modeless dialog by sending messages to the main thread. This way you can minimize the main form in tray but still show modeless dialog.

Comment: Thanks for answer! How to send messages from server thread to main form?

Comment: Create modeless dialog and give its handle (HWND) to the server thread via the void * data parameter. Use PostMessage or SendMessage to send message to the modeless dialog from the server thread. Be careful with the data that you want modeless dialog to process. The data should be available for the server thread even after PostMessage returns as it will just post & return immediately.

Comment: Can I send messages to CWinThread derived class object, or I need to create some CFrameWnd inside of InitInstance and send messages to it?

Comment: What I am suggesting above is to send messages to the main thread which contains the modeless dialog. If you are going with the approach that @xMRi suggested, then you will have created the modeless dialog in the CWinThread derived class object to which you will send message. The latter approach is more complex.